# Specified Domain does not exist or cant be contacted

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, dns, ip

I'v been trying to add a computer to my domain add-computer -DomainName Gary.psv

but this error pops up "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"

I'm confused Am I suppose to match DNS between both servers? I'm using powershell btw.

Comment: please, _show your code_ that produced the error.

Comment: Can you provide the code that is throwing the error? In general this sounds like a networking or DNS issue.

Comment: The computer that you are running this from needs to know the IP of a writable domain controller in that domain. If the computer is configured with a DNS server that can resolve that domain, then the DNS server response will provide the right answer.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and try to show your code and error message